# Widget class in custom sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, woocommerce, sidebar

I created a custom sidebar with WordPress and I wanted to style it, but here I encounter problem - all widgets which I add to it lose their original class and all styling, also all are wrapped in `<div>` which I declare in function, which is OK, but how can i make each widget keep their original classes passed by WooComerce or give each one unique class ?

Here is code:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ){
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'custom_sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="shop-top">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misinterpreted the arguments of [register_sidebar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar). In order to maintain the classes of each widget you cannot hard-code each widget to have the ID of "shop-top". Try the folowing:

```
$args = array(
    'name'          => __( 'Custom Sidebar', 'theme_text_domain' ),
    'id'            => 'shop-top',
    'description'   => '',
        'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>' );

register_sidebar( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you :) , yes yesterday at night i figured it out :) it was exactly this what you point out.